# Squish GUI testing for Java, use windows primary mouse button rather than set mouse button manually?

Tags: python, java, testing, squish

My workplace uses Squish for testing our Java gui, and I recently had an issue where no tests would run properly on my machine, we eventually worked out that this was due to the fact that I use a left-handed mouse, and on windows have set right-click as my primary mouse button. However our squish setup seems to manually call left click, I'm looking to find a way to make squish respect the primary mouse button as set by windows? We use python as our scripting language for Squish tests.

Any help on this front would be appreciated, its definitely an edge-case, but one that took long enough to solve that we don't want to run into it again.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem, but Qt doesn't document this very well in the API documentation, which is very annoying. I had to dig through my squish directory to find the answer. I opened the folder in VSCode and did a search for "primaryButton". I found a file called `mouseconstants.def` (at `SQUISH_DIR/sdk/common`), inside which I found multiple mouse buttons defined as integers. Each is set to a power of 2, which I suppose makes sense, as I believe they're reading the mouseButton parameter as a byte, so each button is associated with a specific bit flag. Nevertheless, here are the values:

```
SQUISH_CONSTANT(LeftButton, 1)
SQUISH_CONSTANT(MiddleButton, 2)
SQUISH_CONSTANT(RightButton, 4)
SQUISH_CONSTANT(Wheel, 8)
SQUISH_CONSTANT(PrimaryButton, 16)
SQUISH_CONSTANT(SecondaryButton, 32)
SQUISH_CONSTANT(XButton1, 64)
SQUISH_CONSTANT(XButton2, 128)
```

To solve your problem, I would try to use `16` whenever you need a primary ("left") button, and `32` whenever you need a secondary ("right") click.

This may only work on Windows, as there's this note on [Squish's API](https://doc.qt.io/squish/squish-api.html#squish-api-function-parameters):

> Note: Windows test suites also support two more possible mouse button
> specifiers, MouseButton.PrimaryButton and MouseButton.SecondaryButton.
> These values respect the global Windows setting used to swap the mouse
> buttons. If the buttons are not swapped (the default), the left button
> is the primary button. Otherwise, the right button is the primary
> button.